# Creating a RasterLayer

Tags: r, layer, raster, sampling

I'm trying to create a raster layer from a matrix that contains in the columns the species names, longitude and latitude.

The data name is "base", and when I try to create the rasterlayer with the extent of `base` with the command

```
r<-raster(base)
```

I get an error:

```
Error en .local(x, ...) : list has no "x"
```

Would you help me? thanks

Comment: There is a chance that your 'base' is a dataframe. Using `as.matrix(base)` may resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give us much to go on, but you might like to try this (the example below *ASSUMES* that your coordinate data is in lat-long format using the WGS84 datum. If it is not the representation of your points in 2-D space will be wrong, so please try to find your projection information...

```
require( sp )
require( raster )
require( maptools )


#Some dummy data in the format you have described
base <- data.frame( longitude = sample( c(-20:20) , 10 ) , latitude = sample( c(-30:30) , 10 ) , species = sample( letters[1:3] , 10 , repl = TRUE ) )
head( base )
#     longitude latitude species
#   1       -10        7       a
#   2         3       14       b
#   3        -9       29       b
#   4        -8      -25       a
#   5         0      -19       b
#   6       -19       19       c

#Make spatial points dataframe, which will have a spatial extent
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame( base[ c("longitude" , "latitude") ] , data = data.frame( base$species ) , proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") )

#make raster based on the extent of your data
r <- raster( extent( spdf ) )
r
#   class       : RasterLayer 
#   dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#   resolution  : 3.3, 5.8  (x, y)
#   extent      : -20, 13, -29, 29  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#   coord. ref. : NA 
#   values      : none
```